# How to get the first function call argument via AST?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to get arguments from a function call. For example we have such function call sample:

```
self.assertEqual(dictlike.fromkeys('a'), {'a':None})
```

I use such code:

```
import ast


class CallVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_Call(self, node):
        print('Node type: Call\nFields: ', node._fields)
        ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)

    def visit_Name(self, node):
        print('Node type: Name\nFields: ', node._fields)
        ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)

    def visit_Constant(self, node):
        print('Node type: Constant\nFields: ', node._fields)
        ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)

    def visit_keyword(self, node):
        print('Node type: keyword\nFields: ', node._fields)
        ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)

    def visit_FunctionDef(self,node):
        print('Node type: FunctionDef\nFields:', node.fields)
        ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    source = """self.assertEqual(dictlike.fromkeys('a'), {'a':None})"""

    root = ast.parse(source)
    for node in ast.walk(root):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Name) and isinstance(node.ctx, ast.Store):
            print(node.id)
        elif isinstance(node, ast.Attribute):
            print(node.attr)
```

and I receive such output:

```
assertEqual
fromkeys
```

I also tried to get it from the dump:
print (ast.dump(node))

but I didn't manage to get certain field:

```
Module(body=[Expr(value=Call(func=Attribute(value=Name(id='self', ctx=Load()), attr='assertEqual', ctx=Load()), args=[Call(func=Attribute(value=Name(id='dictlike', ctx=Load()), attr='fromkeys', ctx=Load()), args=[Constant(value='a', kind=None)], keywords=[]), Dict(keys=[Constant(value='a', kind=None)], values=[Constant(value=None, kind=None)])], keywords=[]))], type_ignores=[])
```

for example I tried such way:

```
print(node.args[0])
```

finally I would like to receive:

```
dictlike.fromkeys('a')
```

maybe I did something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are attempting to extract the parameters from assertion test cases in your source, you can use `ast.walk`:

```
import ast
source = """self.assertEqual(dictlike.fromkeys('a'), {'a':None})"""
r = [[*map(ast.unparse, i.args+i.keywords)] for i in ast.walk(ast.parse(source)) 
     if isinstance(i, ast.Call) and getattr(i.func, 'attr', '').startswith('assert')]
```

Output:

```
[["dictlike.fromkeys('a')", "{'a': None}"]]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I received this error from your code execution - `AttributeError: module 'ast' has no attribute 'unparse'` and also such warning I have `Expected type 'List[expr]' (matched generic type 'List[_T]'), got 'List[keyword]' instead` in the code

Comment: @Andrew `ast.unparse` is only available in Python versions >=3.9.